# Neither Submit working Nor Inserting data in DB

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, forms

I am using login and registration in the same page. Here is my HTML Code~~

```css
body {
    margin:0 !important ;
    padding:0 !important ;

}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('image/innerScream.jpg');
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: repeat;

}

.card{
    width: 350px;
    height: 500px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    perspective: 1000px;
    border-radius: 1em;
}

.inner-box{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

.card-front, .card-back{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0 0 100 / 38%), rgb(0 27 100)), url(image/mirrorWindow.jpg);
    padding: 55px;
    padding-top: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 1em;
}

.card-back{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card h2{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

.input-box{
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    margin: 6px 0;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

::placeholder{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
}

button{
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    margin: 35px 0 10px;
    height: 32px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.submit-btn {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 55%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 6em;
}

.submit-btn::after{
    content: '\27a4';
    color: #333;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    right: -1px;
    top: -1px;
}

span{
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.card .btn {
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.card a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.check{
    margin-left: 5em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.massage{
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<?php 
    require_once "register.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Memories - A NoteBook </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="inner-box" id="card" >
            <div class="card-front">
                    <h2>Memories - A NoteBook</h2>
                    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                        <input type="email" class=" input-box" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email Id" name="email" required>
                        <input type="password" class=" input-box" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
                        <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Login"> Login </button>
                        <input class="check" type="checkbox"><span>Remember Me</span>
                    </form>
                    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="openRegister()"> I am New Here </button>
                    <a href="">Forgot Password?</a>
                </div>

                <div class="card-back">
                    <h2>Memories - A NoteBook</h2>
                    <?php 
                        if(isset($massage)){
                            foreach($massage as $msg){
                                echo '<div class="massage" style="color:red;">'.$massage.'</div>';
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
                        <input type="text" class=" input-box" placeholder=" Enter Your Name" name="name" required>
                        <input type="email" class=" input-box" placeholder=" Enter Your Email " name="email" required>
                        <input type="password" class=" input-box" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
                        <input type="password" class=" input-box" placeholder="Re-Type Password" name="cpassword" required>
                        <input type="file" class="upload-button" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" name="image" required>
                        <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Register"> Register </button>
                        
                    </form>
                    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="openLogin()"> I've an Account !! </button>
                    <a href="">Forgot Password?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>

        var card = document.getElementById("card");

        function openRegister(){
            card.style.transform = "rotateY(-180deg)";
        }

        function openLogin(){
            card.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)";
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The problem is**

When I hit submit button for register the user It doesn't Insert data into data table. and doesn't redirect my desired page. After submitting it only redirect the login form. Here is the php code ~~

```
<?php 

//include config file
include "config.php";

//register user

if (isset($_POST['submit']) ){
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, md5 ($_POST['password']) );
    $cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, md5 ($_POST['cpassword']) );
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image_folder = "images/".$image;


    //check if email already exists
    $select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email' AND userpassword = '$password' ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($select) > 0){
        $massage[] = "User already exists";
    }else{
        if($password != $cpassword){
            $massage[] = "Password does not match";
        }elseif($image_size > 5097152){
        $massage[] = "Image size should be less than 5MB";
        }else{
            $insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO user (username, email, userpassword, Image) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$password', '$image')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            if($insert){
                move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, $image_folder);
                $massage[] = "Registration successful";
                header("location: home.php");
            }else{
                $massage[] = "Registration failed";
            } 
        }  
    }
   
}
```

?>

[Here is my table information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgbb4.png)

> Database is successfully connected and it's showing the success alert

Comment: Any error messages in the web server (Apache/nginx/etc) log?

Answer (score 1):

The name attribute is missing in the definition of your register button:

```
<button type="submit" name="register" class="submit-btn" value="Register"> Register </button>
```

Then you can call:

```
if (isset($_POST['register']) ){......
```